# How do I perform IO inside a WAI (Warp) Application

Tags: haskell, io

I have a simple WAI application (Warp in this case) that responds to all web requests with "Hi".  I also want it to display "Said hi" on the server each time a request is processed.  How do I perform IO inside my WAI response handler?  Here's my application:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "http://localhost:3000/"
    run 3000 app

app :: Application
app _ = return hello

hello = responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "Hi"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type of a WAI application is:

```
type Application = Request -> Iteratee ByteString IO Response
```

This means that a WAI application runs in an `Iteratee` monad transformer over `IO`, so you'll have to use `liftIO` to perform regular `IO` actions.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans

app _ = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Said hi"
    return hello
```

Comment: I just wasted a few hours Googling and this was the answer. Where is one supposed to learn about topics like this when getting into Haskell?